# flutter_session and shared_preferences not work together in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, session, sharedpreferences

Because hr depends on flutter_session ^0.1.1 which depends on shared_preferences ^0.5.8, shared_preferences ^0.5.8 is required.
So, because hr depends on shared_preferences ^2.0.4, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because hr depends on shared_preferences ^2.0.4, version solving failed.) Process finished with exit code 1

my pubspec.yaml code

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_session: ^0.1.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.4
```

how to overcome it?

Answer (score 2):

`flutter_session: ^0.1.1` depends on dart sdk 2.7.0 whilst `shared_preferences: ^2.0.4`  depends on dart sdk 2.12, hence the error.

you might have to use this pull request  for `flutter_session` which is updated to flutter 2.0 and latest dart sdk
https://github.com/jhourlad/flutter_session/pull/11

in pubspec.yaml

```
flutter_session:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/RomanIvn/flutter_session.git
      ref: master
```

Comment: mind that there is a typo in the url (can't edit bc suggested edit queue is full)